# Recursive traversals of binary trees using Lists

Tags: java, binary-tree

This problem has us implementing pre-order, in-order and post-order tree traversals. I generally understand how traversals work. We need to implement the traversals in recursive faction. The problem comes with a `TreeNode` class (read-only; see code below).
I thought this would be fairly straight-forward but doesn't seem to be working correctly. The problem suggests we use wrapper methods to get the recursion to work properly but I'm not 100% clear on what that means.
My code (see below) generates an error similar to the following for all three methods:

[Test Failure: preorder] [-1.43] : Incorrect preorder traversal.

```
+-------------------------------------+
| Tree State :                        |
|                                     |
|               5                     |
|        /               \            |
|       4                 7           |
|    /                       \        |
|   1                         9       |
|  /   \                   /          |
| 0     2                 8           |
|                                     |
| Expected : [5, 4, 1, 0, 2, 7, 9, 8] |
| Actual : [5]                        |
+-------------------------------------+
```

**EDIT / UPDATE**
I can see now that I was re-creating myList each time. This code seems to work as expected:

```
public List<T> preorder(TreeNode<T> root) {
    List<T> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (root != null) {
        myList.add(root.getData());
        myList.addAll(preorder(root.getLeft()));
        myList.addAll(preorder(root.getRight()));
    }
    return myList;
}
```

However, doesn't this also create a new myList each time preorder is called?

`Traversals` class:

```java
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    
    /**
     * Your implementation of the pre-order, in-order, and post-order
     * traversals of a tree. Must be done recursively
     */
    public class Traversals<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
    
        /**
         * DO NOT ADD ANY GLOBAL VARIABLES!
         */
        public List<T> preorder(TreeNode<T> root) {
            List<T> myList = new ArrayList<>();
            if (root != null) {
                myList.add(root.getData());
                preorder(root.getLeft());
                preorder(root.getRight());
            }
            return myList;
        }
    

        public List<T> inorder(TreeNode<T> root) {
            List<T> myList = new ArrayList<>();
            if (root != null) {
                inorder(root.getLeft());
                myList.add(root.getData());
                inorder(root.getRight());
            }
            return myList;
        }
    
        public List<T> postorder(TreeNode<T> root) {
            List<T> myList = new ArrayList<>();
            if (root != null) {
                postorder(root.getLeft());
                postorder(root.getRight());
                myList.add(root.getData());
            }
            return myList;
        }
    }
```

`TreeNode` class:

````java
        public class TreeNode<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {
    
        private T data;
        private TreeNode<T> left;
        private TreeNode<T> right;
    
        /**
         * Constructs a TreeNode with the given data.
         * @param data the data stored in the new node
         */
        TreeNode(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    
        /**
         * Gets the data.
         * @return the data
         */
        T getData() {
            return data;
        }
    
        /**
         * Gets the left child.
         * @return the left child
         */
        TreeNode<T> getLeft() {
            return left;
        }
    
        /**
         * Gets the right child.
         * @return the right child
         */
        TreeNode<T> getRight() {
            return right;
        }
    
        /**
         * Sets the data.
         * @param data the new data
         */
        void setData(T data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    
        /**
         * Sets the left child.
         * @param left the new left child
         */
        void setLeft(TreeNode<T> left) {
            this.left = left;
        }
    
        /**
         * Sets the right child.   
         * @param right the new right child
         */
        void setRight(TreeNode<T> right) {
            this.right = right;
        }
      }
```java
````

Comment: Well, you are only ever returning a new list you add at most a single item to. You don't preserver the state of the list at any point. That is what you need wrapper methods for

Comment: Maybe I'm really not understanding something (highly likely). But first we pass in node 5 as the root, to preorder. It checks to see if the node is null. It's not, so 5 is added to my List. Then it calls preorder on the left child node, which here is 4. It checks to see if it is null. It's not, so 4 should be added to myList, then preorder called on the 4 left child node, which is 1...and so on and so on. That's how I envisioned it working in my head...?

Comment: That is kinda correct, except you always re-create `myList`, making it an empty list you add to. In the end you only return a list with 1 entry, which is `5`

Answer (score 1):

The traversal order done by you is good, the problem is that whenever you call `preorder(root.getLeft());` or `preorder(root.getRight());` you don't do anything about the result of the operation.
The only place where you add anything to the result list is `myList.add(root.getData());`. Computation of left and right trees is ignored.

I believe the simplest way to do it is just by adding results like this: `myList.addAll(preorder(root.getRight()));`

In recursion there is a common 'trick' to use a helper method, usually with accumulator argument, that your main method just calls. I believe that's what they mean by wrapper methods. I don't think it's useful in this case, considering given methods' signatures.

Comment: See my comment above, but: first we pass in node 5 as the root, to preorder. It checks to see if the node is null. It's not, so 5 is added to my List. Then it calls preorder on the left child node, which here is 4. It checks to see if it is null. It's not, so 4 should be added to myList, then preorder called on the 4 left child node, which is 1...and so on and so on. That's how I envisioned it working in my head; aren't we adding something to myList every time we pass a non-null node to the method?

Or am I creating a new list each time it's called?

Comment: You are creating a new list each time a method is called. Which is not suprising, since `new ArrayList<>()` is called every time.

Comment: Txs - I actually got it to work by utilizing your suggestion. BUT - doesn't `myList.addAll(preorder(root.getRight()));` also call preorder, and thus recreate a new myList each time it's called?

Comment: @Dragon-Ash It does. And then you're taking the list that you created inside `preorder(root.getRight())` and add all of its content to your "base" list. This way the new list and its content isn't ignored.